# Writing and reading into Web .Config

Tags: c#, .net, web-config

I have 4 textboxes with button. On button click all the values should go and store in web .config in app settings. I need to store them in a value. I have a password textbox also. This password should save in a encrypted format. Help me to do this.

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="Setting1" value="myName" />
    <add key="Setting2" value="myDob" />
 </appSettings>
```

Comment: make use of linq to xml....that will help you..

Comment: no this is direct storing

Comment: This has nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

I completed this,

```js
// Writing / Modifying app setting value

            Configuration webConfigApp = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
            webConfigApp.AppSettings.Settings["datasource"].Value = TextBox1.Text;
            webConfigApp.AppSettings.Settings["initialcatalog"].Value = TextBox2.Text;
            webConfigApp.AppSettings.Settings["userid"].Value = TextBox3.Text;
           
            // Encrypt password in app setting

            TextBox4.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(TextBox4.Text));
            webConfigApp.AppSettings.Settings["password"].Value = TextBox4.Text;
            webConfigApp.Save();
```